# Pass SELECT result to a PL/SQL function, that requires nested table as parameter

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

So I have a type:

```
create or replace TYPE t_text IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200)
```

And a function, that uses t_text type for a  input value, but this

```
function(
(SELECT CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name FROM table_name) AS T_TEXT)  FROM DUAL)
)
```

is not working properly. I can't create the collection before, because this function is used in a view. Is there any workaround?

**Edit:** Actually, the precise problem is that in

```
select multiple_replace( 
  'text', 
  CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name1 FROM table_name) AS T_TEXT), 
  CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name2 FROM table_name) AS T_TEXT) 
) A from dual;
```

the elements in two colletions are not in the same order as they were in the table. So the results are different from creating collections with **bulk collect**, that I can't use for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT function(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name FROM table_name) AS T_TEXT))
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you, I elaborated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's just as simple as

```
select multiple_replace( 
  'text', 
  CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name1 FROM table_name ORDER BY id) AS T_TEXT), 
  CAST(MULTISET(SELECT column_name2 FROM table_name ORDER BY id) AS T_TEXT) 
) A from dual;
```

Comment: What is `multiple_replace()`? It doesn't appear to be a standard function..?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom function I found, that uses replace('text', collection1(i), collection2(i)) in a loop.